# OpenERP manually installed addon not found

Tags: openerp-7

I'm a newbie in OpenERP (Odoo) and using version 7 on Ubuntu. I downloaded [this app](https://www.odoo.com/apps/7.0/l10n_tn/) and put it in the addons folder, I also changed its ownership to the openerp user but somehow I can't find it when I go to Modules->Installed Applications.

Please help

Comment: how did you install , you have to locate the addons path
please provide specfication
or error logs
and if possible how are you starting server
and openerp installation path

Comment: I installed OpenERP in /opt/openerp. And I extracted the module zip in  /opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons. The log directory is empty there are no errors

Comment: I told you there are no errors. I just can't find my installed module in the installed module list in OpenERP. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

run by following

```
path/to/openerp/openerp-server -c openerp-server.conf
```

and create a openerp-server.conf like this

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
; admin_passwd = admin
db_host = False
db_port = False
db_password = False
db_user = your_computer_user
;log_level = debug_sql
log_level = info
logfile = path/to/logfile.log
addons_path =path/to/addonsfolder1,/path/t/addonsfolder2
```

in you case addons path will be

```
addons_path =/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons
```

Thanks

let me know if problem exists

Comment: Hi, Thank your for your help, here's my configuration file located in /etc/openerp-server.conf
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
; admin_passwd = admin
db_host = False
db_port = False
db_user = openerp
db_password = root
logfile = /var/log/openerp/openerp-server.log
addons_path = /opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons

I added the addons_path property but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Pls update the module lists and uncheck the installed filter in the search bar of installed modules and try. This will solve your problem.
Thanks And Regards

Comment: I did that and I didn't find the installed module in the installed modules list. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

1. Logout from app
2. Restart openerp service
3. Login to openerp
4. Update the module lists and uncheck the installed filter in the search bar of installed modules

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I did that and I can't find it anywhere :/